# Arch x86_64 Linux ROS core build fails

Tags: ros, python, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When i try to build the ROS core on Arch Linux x86_64 system i get the following error, if some one could help me solve this or at least point me in the rite direction would be very helpful

The error is below:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/rxloggerlevel
[100%] Built target rxconsole
In file included from /tmp/yaourt-tmp-zion/aur-ros-core/src/ros-underlay/build/rx/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp:3240:0:
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/wxPython/wxPython.h: In function 'bool wxPyCoreAPI_IMPORT()':
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/wxPython/wxPython.h:39:80: error: 'PyCObject_Import' was not declared in this scope
[100%] Built target rxloggerlevel
make[2]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/python_rxtools.dir/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/python_rxtools.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX shared library ../../../lib/librosbag.so
[100%] Built target rosbag
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45411/arch-x86_64-linux-ros-core-build-fails/) by [vijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3350/vijay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-09**:
Take a look here.. it may be a new swig issue in rxtool... http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1365 good luck.

**Comment by [vijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3350/vijay/) on 2012-10-10**:
Hi Lorenz,
Thanks for your response, i tried cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 ..
looked for any reference to python in the build directory there was none but i still get the same errro :( any ideas

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-11**:
Have a look at CMakeCache.txt. There should be something related to libpython.

**Comment by [vijay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3350/vijay/) on 2012-10-12**:
Thanks Lorenz looks like that solved the python problem but now i face a boost problem i think http://answers.ros.org/question/45689/ros-core-build-on-arch-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That seems to be another python issue. My guess is that cmake's configure finds python3 instead of python2. If you are lucky, you can change that using ccmake. Go into your build directory, execute `cmake .` and check if the configure contains something python3 related. Change it to the corresponding files/directories/flags for python2. If that doesn't work, you might have to patch some catkin cmake files that are responsible for finding python.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3